# What is the word beginning "hom..." meaning an explanation in terms of persons and their actions?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word just escapes me, but it is frequently used politically to describe a narrative which relies on explaining a complex matter in terms of the people involved in the issue.

Comment: Sounds like humanized. >"The humanized brand will communicate the message, either directly or in a subtle way, that the bank understands its customers as humans, cares about what they are feeling and is committed to meeting their needs."  thefreelibrary.com/Humanizing+bank+brands-a0374971457

Comment: Add a sample sentence please. It may help to find the word.

Comment: @Josh I've just remembered - the expression I'm thinking of is *ad hominem*. My apologies for troubling you. Others should consider the question closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know for sure without more context, but you may be thinking of **ad hominem**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem

In politics (and logic/rhetoric more broadly), it refers to arguments that target a person or their character instead of targeting the merits of their argument.

It's considered a logical fallacy and is often used in political discourse.